# What does the <> means in an iOS class header?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The `AppDelegate.h` file contains the following at the top of the line:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

The current class is `AppDelegate` which is a subclass of `UIResponder`.  What is the relationship of `UIApplicationDelegate` with the current class?

Comment: its says, AppDelegate responds to those protocols (UIAppDelegate protocol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It declares that the class conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

An Objective-C protocol is similar to a Java interface: it can declare method signatures but it can't provide method implementations.

The compiler will warn you if your `@implementation` is missing any of the `@required` methods of the protocol.  Xcode will autocomplete any of the methods (`@required` or `@optional`) of the protocol.

You can declare conformance to multiple protocols by separating them with commas.  Example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Read [*Cocoa Core Competencies*: Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Protocol.html) and [*Programming with Objective-C*: Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11).

Comment: Are there documentations which explains what <> mean?  What is it similar to in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

This mean that your class implement `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. Here you have something about protocols : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Protocol.html

You must implement a required methods from implemented protocol into your class, if you want to have class fully accordance with the protocol.